# php N elements in if statement with or

Tags: php

this is what I want to do:

```
$myArray = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3',...,'valueN'];

if ($myArray[0] == 'string' || $myArray[1] == 'string' || $myArray[2] == 'string' ||...|| $myArray[N] == 'string'){ 
echo 'error'; 
} else { 
echo 'success'; 
}
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Google: `PHP in_array()`

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you if your array contains any element with the value 'string':

```
if ( in_array('string', $myArray) ) {
  echo 'error';
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

This will tell you if your array contains any element of type 'string':

```
$result = 'success';

foreach ($myArray as $element) {
    if ( gettype($element) == 'string' ) {
       $result = 'error';
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) built-in function:

```
if (in_array('string', $myArray)) { 
    echo 'error'; 
} else { 
    echo 'success'; 
}
```